# On mouse over image in div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

I would like to have "links", those are not real links, they are in fact titles of equipment or something I want to review.

On mouse over that title I would like image change, but what I want is that after mouse is out of that title, last image stays there.

I got some code that I don't like. It can be jquery, css, javascript, I would implement it on wordpress site.

Simple idea is, that I would have for example:

PICTURE GOES HERE

Equipment 1: front | back | side
Equipment 2: front | back | side

At first Equipment 1: front is opened above. 
After mouse over any other: front, back or side, picture would load but would not change until I go mouse over another text (front,back or side).

Pre-load would be ok as well, but I already have it on site. It would be great that it works just as regular images on WP, so if I click on picture it goes to full size picture or link, mouse over picture gives caption (title) etc. If not possible nvm.

It should look exactly as http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Tamron-18-270mm-f-3.5-6.3-Di-II-VC-Lens-Review.aspx , find image with more titles under it, and go mouse over those.

I have jquery that doesn't work at all and code with css, that on mouse out changes picture, but I don't want to change on mouse out.

JQUERY - Tryout 1 - doesn't work, checked it is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#picture_links a").hover(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#picture_holder img").attr("src", src);
    })

    $("#picture_links a").click(function(){
        return false;
    })

})
</script>
```

CSS - different script, works, but not as I want:

```
/* On mouse image roll over */

img.nohover {
border:0
}
img.hover {
border:0;
display:none
}
a:hover img.hover {
display:inline
}
a:hover img.nohover {
display:none
}
```

Comment: Can we see what you have so far, code-wise?

Comment: There is no question ? Well I have code that doesn't work and I don't want that code, .. :(

Answer (score 0):

use

```
jQuery("elementid").mouseover(function() 
{
    var imageId = jQuery(this).attr("imageID");
    var image = jQuery(this).css('background-image');

    var newImageId = imageId++;
    if (newImageId >= 3)
        newImageId = 0;

    var newImage = image.replace(imageID, newImageId);
    jQuery(this).css({ "background-image": "newImage " })

}
```

this only works if your images are named sequentially. 
don't have numbers in the actual name besides the sequence number
and if you add an attribute named imageId to your divs.

Comment: Am I allowed to post example link to page that is not mine of exactly what I want.

Comment: just put it in your original post aslong as you don't take credit i'm sure noone will object.

Comment: I sure hope that somebody replies :(

Answer (score 0):

They do it this way

```
function chgimage(imgDocID,imgObjName)
{
    document[imgDocID].src = eval(imgObjName + '.src');
}
```

do you want it to be an actual image or can it be a background?

your first piece of code looks fine.
can you show us what it does somewhere? i'm curious.